# Emma not recognizing that an anonymous inner class is being tested

Tags: android, ant, emma

I've got a class that spawns a thread and a test that validates the results. Emma isn't reporting code coverage for the thread even through I can step through in the debugger and see that it's being tested. Can anyone see why this would be happening and tell me how to fix it?

**The method that spawns the thread**

```
private static String deviceName = DEFAULT_DEVICE_NAME;
protected void initializeDeviceName() {
    if (deviceName.equals(DEFAULT_DEVICE_NAME)) {
        DeviceContext.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                deviceName = DeviceManager.getDeviceName();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**The test**

```
public void testGetDeviceName() {
    DeviceManager.setDeviceName(DEVICE_NAME);
    // constructor calls initializeDeviceName()
    iconListener = new HealthIconListener(view); 
    sleep(SHORT_SLEEP_TIME);
    assertEquals(DEVICE_NAME, HealthIconListener.getDeviceName());
}
```

**The relevant methods in DeviceContext**

```
private static ExecutorService getExecutor() {
    if (executor == null) {
        executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    }
    return executor;
}

public static void execute(Runnable task) {
    getExecutor().execute(task);
}
```